# How to make a Logon script secure in windows

Tags: windows, security, powershell, batch-file

I have a logon batch script that runs a .reg file for all user when they log in. here's my script

```
@echo running
REGEDIT.EXE /S "C:\user_files\user.reg"
```

Now my concern is that the batch file itself is located in

```
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts
```

Every user has access to this directory. So anyone can change the batch and may cause security threat. Is there a way to make it more secure. or is can I do something similar with PowerShell scripting so there's no batch. If someone could point me to the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: A logon script has to be readable to any user in order to execute it. They should not be able to modify it however. You can test this yourself by logging on as a standard user, and then try to edit the script. You should get a "access denied" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your script needs to be readable by your users, but you can take away their rights to modify it -- that's a typical file system feature that every Windows since NT has (aside from windows 9x, of course).

Hence, simply remove the write privileges from the user group in which your users are, and you're fine.

Comment: thank you works perfectly. Took down the user privilege for regular users.